# How to show multiple download progress using ASINetworkQueue

Tags: iphone, multithreading, download, asihttprequest, uiprogressview

I want to perform the downloads on multiple button clicks and these are buttons are created dynamically. And each button is assigned with different urls.

I want to perform multiple download operations at the same time, and also want to update the download progress of each download on different `UIProgressView`s.

I was told that to use `ASINetworkQueue` method, but in this one, how can I add requests dynamically to the queue? Or is there any other way or sample code?

Please help.

Sample code:

```
- (void)fetchThisURLFiveTimes:(NSURL *)url
{
   [myQueue cancelAllOperations];
   [myQueue setDownloadProgressDelegate:myProgressIndicator];
   [myQueue setDelegate:self];
   [myQueue setRequestDidFinishSelector:@selector(queueComplete:)];
   int i;
   for (i=0; i<5; i++) {
      ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
      [myQueue addOperation:request];
   }
   [myQueue go];
}

- (void)queueComplete:(ASINetworkQueue *)queue
{
   NSLog(@"Value: %f", [myProgressIndicator progress]);
}
```

Comment: Read NSOperationQueue for multiple operations in queue.

Comment: have you set self.myQueue = [ASINetworkQueue queue] ?

Answer (score 1):

simple add new Operations/Requests to the queue:

```
  [networkQueue addOperation:<#(NSOperation *)#>]
  [networkQueue addOperations:<#(NSArray *)#> waitUntilFinished:<#(BOOL)#>]
```

and you can track the progress for an specific Request by setting the:

```
  [request setDownloadProgressDelegate:<#(id)#>]
```

> // If the downloadProgressDelegate is an NSProgressIndicator, we set
>   its MaxValue to 1.0 so we can update it as if it were a UIProgressView

Comment: i have tried this, but nothing is happening. I have updated my question with the code that I have used.

Answer (score 1):

I believe ASI has stopped being supported. My company has started using RestKit as an alternative, FYI. See the header at the top of his page: http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/

Comment: I can see that RestKit has covered so many topics, let me check into this. :)